# HTTP 500 while uploading java web on heroku

Tags: java, mysql, http, heroku, servlets

This is my project:
#LoginServlet:

```
package Controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import Uti.Connect2DB;

/**
  Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
**/

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
   
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = Connect2DB.getConnection();
            String n= request.getParameter("txtName");
            String p= request.getParameter("txtPassword");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select username from login where username=? and password=?");  
            ps.setString(1, n);
            ps.setString(2, p);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("admin.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
            else 
            {
                out.print("<a href=login.jsp font-size:33pt margin-left:auto margin-right:auto>TRY AGAIN</a>");
            }
            
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

#web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
         <welcome-file-list> 
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
         </welcome-file-list>
         
         <servlet>  
            <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>Controller.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
         </servlet>
         <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/LoginServlet</url-pattern>
         </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

After deploying successfully on heroku, when I login, I got this error message:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class [Controller.LoginServlet]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [Controller.LoginServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Root Cause

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Controller/LoginServlet has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [Controller.LoginServlet])
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2424)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1334)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Im using tomcat version 8.5

p.s: when deploying on heroku, it was successfully deploy but I show some message:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to delete C:\Users\DABEII~1\AppData\Local\Temp\heroku-deploy13190833225245223655
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable.run(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:46)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\DABEII~1\AppData\Local\Temp\heroku-deploy13190833225245223655\heroku\app\.heroku-deploy: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:275)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:105)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1152)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable$1.visitFile(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:21)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable$1.visitFile(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:16)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2812)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2883)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable.run(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:44)
        ... 1 more
```

Is this the reason of the error I get or something else?
Thank you guys, Im so new for this.

Comment: When I run this on PC, it works correctly, it happens only when I deploy on heroku

Comment: It seems that you are compiling your code with Java 16 (class file version 60.0) - [see here](https://javaalmanac.io/bytecode/versions/), while Heroku is configured for Java 8 (class file version 52.0) - or this is the default. [This document](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/customizing-the-jdk) describes how to change it (haven't tried myself).